# After trying to set a static IP address, my computer can't recognise the network card

Tags: server, static-ip

After installing Ubuntu Server 20.xx, I changed **/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml** content to get a static IP address :

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses: [192.168.1.17/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
  version: 2
```

But when I executed: **sudo netplan apply** it seems like my network card is disconnected and I can't detect the IP address and when I **curl -I http://google.com** I got no response, and the Ethernet lights not blinking.

**Updates:**

```
mostafa@dell-xps:~$ Is -al /etc/netplan
total 12 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 8 19:05 . 
drwxr-xr-x 102 root root 4096 Apr 8 18:11 .. 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117 Apr 8 19:05 00-installer-config.yaml
```

```
mostafa@dell-xps:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml 
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity' 
network: ethernets:
  enp0s3:
    dhcp4: true 
  version: 2
```

```
 
mostafaedell-xps:~$ sudo lshw -C network 
 *-network DISABLED 
     description: Ethernet interface 
     product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
     physical id: 0 
     bus info: pc i®0000:03:00.0 
     logical name: enp3s0 
     version: 06 
     serial: c8:0:66:06:94:al 
     width: 64 bits 
     clock: 33MHz 
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes 
     resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff mostafa@dell-xps:3
```

I rebooted the PC and nothing changed!

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/netplan` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks, you can check the post updates .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incorrect device name in your .yaml file.

Use this for a static address:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.17/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
      optional: true
```

Or this for a dynamic address:

```
network:
  version: 2 
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true 
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: Big thanks it's working again with static IP